# Adding redirect to redirect component from custom component

Tags: joomla-api, custom-component, redirect

Is it possible to add a redirect to the redirect manager from my custom components controller or model? I want my custom component to add a redirect to the redirect manager on deletion of an item. I know i could just add the necessary db query to add this. But i was wondering if there is a more "Joomla Way" of doing this by talking to the redirect component directly.

Kind regards,

Tom

Comment: This seems like a good idea/question.  Have you attempted to self-solve / done any research?  How close did you get?  In the absence of a posted attempt, your post seems to treat this community as a free coding service. From the Close as Off-topic description: **Generally questions that ask for coding a solution must present some effort and that the user is in place to understand what the code is about. For more information, see help center**

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the necessary db query to add this, see:
https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

However, you might be able to instantiate the **RedirectModelLink** model (/administrator/components/com_redirect/models/link.php) and use that to add / delete data.